# difference between string syntax query and dsl query

Tags: elasticsearch

What is the difference between [query-string-syntax](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax) and a [query-dsl-queries](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/query-dsl-queries.html#bool) like boolean query.

Here is two example

```
 field1:value1 AND field2:value2
```

and

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders
                    .boolQuery()
                    .must(termQuery("field1", "value1"))
                    .must(termQuery("field2", "value2"));
```

What is the advantage ,disadvantage of both. Which one preferable?

Answer (score 0):

a query-string is the syntax used when you want to query elasticsearch with the rest api for example when you type :

```
curl -XGET "http://my_ip_adress:9200/my_index/my_type/_search" -d'
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

but query-dsl is used when you're querying elasticsearch with java, so you will have to use a query builder (like in your post) then something like this :

```
client
            .prepareSearch(index)
            .setTypes("my_type")
            .setQuery(qb).execute().actionGet();
```

About advantages, the query dsl are more preferable to use in your program because they are faster. But if you are writing in another language then java, then you have no choice other then using the restapi.

I hope my answer is clear and precise.

Comment: any reason that why `query dsl` is faster cos both are same internally

Comment: yes i think the reason is that elasticsearch is based on java, so when you do the http request, it needs a time to converts the "json" to "java", but when you send the request in java no conversion is needed so it's faster. That's just my guessing.
And by experience the "took" field gives information on the duration the request took, so try the same request on both java and rest api and watch the difference on that field.